# Как реализовать паузу в svg анимации

Tags: css, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Как реализовать задержку в бесконечной анимации?

```html
<svg>
      <circle id="green" r="19" cx="50" cy="50" fill="green" fill-opacity=".82"/>
      <animate
              xlink:href="#green"
              attributeName="r"
              from="19"
              to="30"
              dur="3s"
              begin="3s;green.end+5s"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: я попробую сегодня дать ответ. Заглядывайте в топик.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Добрый вечер,спасибо.Если не трудно можете в пример добавить изменение цвета(в виде градиента под углом).Я уже реализовал,но мне кажется довольно криво.

Comment: Я сначала сделаю на вашем примере с изменением радиуса с паузой, а затем поработаем над изменением градиента. Но наверное вам лучше задать отдельный вопрос по градиенту с примером, что у вас получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Бесконечная анимация увеличения радиуса круга.**

Достигается применением параметра  `repeatCount="indefinite"`

Значение радиуса -`values="19;30"`

*Начало анимации - клик по фигуре*

```html
<svg id="svg2">
      <circle id="green" r="19" cx="50" cy="50" fill="green"  fill-opacity=".82"/>
      <animate id="anim-stroke"
              xlink:href="#green"
              attributeName="r"
              values="19;30"
              dur="5s"
              begin="svg2.click"
     repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

**Анимация увеличения, уменьшения радиуса круга.**

`values="19;30;19"`

```html
<svg id="svg2">
      <circle id="green" r="19" cx="50" cy="50" fill="green"  fill-opacity=".82"/>
      <animate id="anim-stroke"
              xlink:href="#green"
              attributeName="r"
              values="19;30;19"
              dur="5s"
              begin="svg2.click"
     repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

**Пауза в начальном и конечном состоянии круга**

```
values="19;30;30;19;19"
```

```html
<svg id="svg2">
      <circle id="green" r="19" cx="50" cy="50" fill="green"  fill-opacity=".82"/>
      <animate id="anim-stroke"
              xlink:href="#green"
              attributeName="r"
              values="19;30;30;19;19"
              dur="5s"
              begin="svg2.click"
     repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

Пауза достигается повторением в параметре `values` значений.

Арифметика простая: продолжительность всей анимации - 5 сек. Значит паузы будут по 1 сек.

Comment: Здорово!)Я нагуглил только вариант с  id="rad" и  begin="2s;rad.end+2s".

Comment: @Александр Спасибо за оперативность.  жду вопроса по градиентам :)

Comment: А с анимацией градиента  такой вариант <linearGradient><animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</linearGradient>

Comment: @Александр отдельным вопросом пожалуйста оформите. Думаю, это многим будет полезно.

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904789/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-svg