# Анимация градиента SVG под углом

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Как правильно реализовать анимацию градиента SVG элемента под углом и с задержкой?

```css
svg {
  transform: rotate(250deg);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <circle r="27" cx="28" cy="28" fill="url(#lightGradient)"/>
    <linearGradient id="lightGradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(0,99,71, 1)">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="rgba(0,99,71, 0.62); rgba(0,99,71, 0.12)" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(228,210,9, 1)">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="rgba(228,210,9, 0.62); rgba(228,210,9, 0.22)" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Comment: заглядывай в топик, постараюсь сегодня успеть

Comment: может лучше не прозрачность менять, а цвет градиента?

Comment: Можно и цвет, я думаю потом по аналогии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Угол наклона градиента обеспечивают параметры:

  `x1="45" x2="0" y1="75" y2="0"`
- Анимация перехода градиента из одного цвета в другой:

`.crc1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 3s;`

Подбирая значения цвета начального градиента -`stop:first-child`

и конечного - `stop:last-child` можно получить очень интересные эффекты:

*Анимация начинается при наведении курсора:*

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
 .crc1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 3s;
}

.crc1 ~ defs stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #24bed2;
}
.crc1:hover ~ defs stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #F4FFAF;
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 120 120">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  stroke="#F4FFAF"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="45" x2="0" y1="75" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="2%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Возможно глупый вопрос, как Вы подбираете параметры?Почему именно 45 и 75?

Comment: @Александр эти углы связаны с другими параметрами градиента - `stop offset="50%"`  границей перекрытия двух цветов. На словах это сложно объяснить, просто поиграйте с этими параметрами

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT Могу еще отдельный вопрос оформить=))

Comment: @Александр я не против, есть очень интересные варианты

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904824/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-svg-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0