# Как рассчитать координаты градиента SVG элемента

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Как правильно подобрать координаты обеспечивающие угол наклона градиента SVG элемента? Например,-  `220deg?`

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
 .crc1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 3s;
}

.crc1 ~ defs stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #24bed2;
}
.crc1:hover ~ defs stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #F4FFAF;
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 120 120">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  stroke="#F4FFAF"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="2%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, также не забудь описать атрибуты `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Немного теории:

- Координаты `X1, Y1` — начало линии направления действия градиента
- Координаты `X2, Y2` — конец линии направления действия градиента

Для получения **горизонтального градиента** — `x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0"`:

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Чтобы цвета градиента встретились посередине необходимо установить:

```
<stop offset="50%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
<stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
```

**Вертикальный градиент**

`x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100"`

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Градиент под углом `45%`**

`x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="100"` так как параметр `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, то значения `0` и `100` это не проценты, а пиксели. Окно просмотра у нас 200х200px, цвета градиента встречаются на половине, поэтому берем 100px (в svg пиксели можно не указывать)

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="100" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Анимация градиента

Для анимации необходимо изменять координаты

**Анимация горизонтального градиента**

Необходимо добавить всего лишь одну строчку:

```
<animate attributeName="x1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Для более интересного эффекта выбрал границы перекрытия отличающиеся от `50%`:

```
<stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
<stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
```

**Анимация вертикального градиента**

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="4s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Анимация градиента под углом с паузами в конечных точках**

Анимируем сразу две координаты:

```
  <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 200 200">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  />
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F4FFAF"/>
      <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="y1" dur="5s" values="0;200;200;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Класс!Спасибо за ответы на все вопросы)

Answer (score 5):

С помощью `gradientTransform`:

```css
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
 .crc1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 3s;
}

.crc1 ~ defs stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #24bed2;
}
.crc1:hover ~ defs stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #F4FFAF;
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="200px" height="200" viewBox="-10 -10 120 120">
  <circle class="crc1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  stroke="#F4FFAF"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(120)">
      <stop offset="2%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2C2C2C"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я спросил: вы не собираетесь удалять свою учётную запись **здесь** потом? Иначе ответы останутся без хозяина.

Comment: @Bharata, собираюсь, говорил об этом

Comment: Это очень плохо будет для всех – никто не сможет отследить ваши ответы потом. Они будут все разбросаны и вообще будет непонятно чей это ответ. Может всё-таки не будете так делать?

Comment: @Bharata, аккаунт оставлю. Хорошо, я всё равно собирался присудить баллы вам

Comment: Вы перепутали – этот надо было оставить. :-) Но бог с ним уже – теперь можете и другой присудить. Благо дарю!

Comment: @Bharata, я собирался отметить оба:)